# reorder factor levels manually using indices with tidyverse

Tags: r, indices, levels, r-factor

I have a data.frame which contains a factor variable at the beginning.  I would like to first change the order of the factor levels, and then sort the data.frame to be ordered by those factor levels in the new order.

My problem is that the labels for my real factor levels are very long, and I would rather do the re-ordering by indices instead.  I do need to re-order manually as there is no automated sort that would fit my needs.

I tried using indices with `fct_reorder()` however I get incomprehensible results.  The factor is reordered but not in the order I specified by numbers.

How can I use numbers to specify how the factor should be reordered?  I would prefer a tidyverse solution.

Here is what I tried:

```r
# Load tidyverse:
library(tidyverse)

# Create example data frame:

mydf <- data.frame(measure = c("strong", "less strong", "least strong", "fast", "slow"), 
                   cases = c(5,2,11,23,15), 
                   jan = c(2,1,3,4,1), 
                   feb = c(1,0,1,2,3))

mydf <- mydf %>%
         # Convert to factor:
         mutate(measure = factor(measure)) %>%
         # Reorder 'measure' as follows: slow, least strong, less strong, strong, fast
         mutate(measure = fct_reorder(.f = measure, .x = c(4,2,3,5,1))) %>%
         # Arrange data.frame by reordered levels of factor 'measure':
         arrange(measure)
```

Converting to a factor (before manually ordering) gives me this (levels in alphabetical order) which is what I used to determine the indices that I should pass to `fct_reorder()`:

```r
> levels(mydf$measure)
[1] "fast"         "least strong" "less strong"  "slow"        
[5] "strong"
```

The code runs without an error, but I get this, which is not in the order I specified (less strong and least strong are in the wrong place):

```r
> mydf
       measure cases jan feb
1         slow    15   1   3
2  less strong     2   1   0
3 least strong    11   3   1
4       strong     5   2   1
5         fast    23   4   2
```

I also tried starting the level numbers with a `0` instead of `1` which reorders the levels again but still not the order I wanted them in.  There doesn't seem to be any logic (that I can see) in how it is reordering either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fct_relevel()` to relevel by your indices:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

mydf %>%
  mutate(measure = fct_relevel(measure, levels(measure)[c(4,2,3,5,1)])) %>%
  arrange(measure)

       measure cases jan feb
1         slow    15   1   3
2 least strong    11   3   1
3  less strong     2   1   0
4       strong     5   2   1
5         fast    23   4   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you I found the fct_order arguments to have a confusing interpretation. So why not just use standard factor modification like this:

```
levels(mydf$measure) <- c('slow', 'least strong', 'less strong', 'strong', 'fast')
mydf <- mydf %>%  
     arrange(measure)
mydf
#----fixed---------
dplyr::arrange(mydf, measure)
#---------------
       measure cases jan feb
1         slow    15   1   3
2 least strong    11   3   1
3  less strong     2   1   0
4       strong     5   2   1
5         fast    23   4   2
```

Comment: The issue is that `arrange()` only orders by alphanumeric order (increasing or decreasing).  In my real data set, the order that I wanted the factor levels to be in is not alphabetical - rather the meaning of the words suggests a specific order.  I tried to illustrate that with my example, where slow should be the first value even though l comes before s and so on). The order that I wanted to change them to is better represented by your first line `levels(mydf$measure)...`

Comment: @AmyM : That was really surprising to me. Was expecting it to use the factor levels ordering. Would have been a blatant disregard for what an experienced R programmer would expect to do otherwise.  (What it instead shows is that I didn't read my own set of results, since the error was in my construction of the levels argument.) Now fixed and it succeeds.